# Query to find user who matches the conditions (MongoDB/NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to find a user who matchs the conditions I put in the query,

I want to find the user where :
- who has the same email than the req.body.email,
- who has the same token than the req.body.resetPasswordToken,
- who has a resetPasswordExpires in the future

Here's the query in a NodeJS route :

```
User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email,
      resetPasswordToken: req.body.resetPasswordToken,
      resetPasswordExpires: {
        $gt: new Date()
      }
    }
  })
```

There's a user who's supposed to match, but there's no match returned,

What's wrong in my query please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Mongo, you dont need the `where`:

```
User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email,
      resetPasswordToken: req.body.resetPasswordToken,
      resetPasswordExpires: {
        $gt: new Date()
      }
  })
```

See documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/